# count in mysql by each value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

My table:

```
 salesName    |    customerName    |     OrderNumber    |
 A            |        H           |          01        |
 A            |        H           |          02        |       
 A            |        I           |          03        |

 B            |        J           |          04        |
 B            |        J           |          05        |
 B            |        J           |          06        |
 B            |        K           |          07        |
 B            |        K           |          08        |
 B            |        L           |          09        |
```

How to get this output:

to know performance of the sales, total customers each of them(sales),
how many order from their customers

```
salesName  |  customer  |  order
   A       |     2      |    3
   B       |     3      |    6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please dont put images; they are harder to read and irreproducible. Please put the sample data as formatted text. Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Do you really have a id with 0 value? That looks wierd.

Comment: oh sorry i'm just a newbie in stackoverflow :D
it was work, thanks.

i'm using dataframe in jupyter notebook to visualizing my database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select salesname, count(distinct customername) as num_customers,
       count(*) as num_orders
from t
group by salesname;
```

Comment: i have update my question, can you help me please?

Comment: @Ruzannah . . . It is the same answer.